# How to model set of global variables

Tags: uml, sysml

I have to model the sequence of an initalization. 
In this sequence one module A has to set globals of a module B.

So how can I model this in UML.

As there is no message or event I can't draw an arrow from Module A to Module B.

My idea was to just set note or label next to the lifeline of Module A that the globals of Module B will be set.

But this feels not realy "clean".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, module B does not have an operation (`setGlobals` or individual setters) to set the variables. Module B does not have proper encapsulation. This is undesirable, but I will accept it as a fact.

In general, a sequence diagram is meant to show the message exchange between objects (in your case: modules). Since there is no message exchange for setting the variables, you may consider not showing this action in the sequence diagram at all.

If you do want to show the action in the sequence diagram, because it is an important step in the process, I would recommend to design a private method in module A to set the variables, e.g. `setGlobalsOfModuleB` and then call it:

[image: sd]

Alternatively, you could use a note.

Answer (score 2):

A note would be fairly ok. It's also ok to send a message since basically there's no difference whether to access an attribute or a global variable. You would likely mark that global variable as an attribute with an stereotype like `<<global>>` or what ever.

As a side note: SDs are not invented for graphical programming and you should not put every single detail in one SD. They are there to illustrate complicated object interaction scenarios and help communicating them. Leave space to the coders since they are no stupid machines that need every bit exactly to be defined.

Comment: I need to define the Interfaces between the modules and the interaction, so from SW architecture point of view there should be no place for interpretation. (even for the coder) :)

Comment: If you're going to that level you're actually coding in UML. There are ways to be strict and clear on a higher level. Thinking in "global variable" categories indicates that you're on the wrong level. I guess this discussion would go too far. Do what you think you should. The above is just a _side note._